# how to turn a for loop with if statement working on datetime df into a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to  turn the below for loop with if statement into a list comprehension.

```
# Create dictionary to hold results
    trip_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

# Loop over all trips
for trip in onebike_datetimes:
  # Check to see if the trip starts before noon
  if trip['start'].hour < 12:
    # Increment the counter for before noon
    trip_counts["AM"] += 1
  else:
    # Increment the counter for after noon
    trip_counts["PM"] += 1
```

I tried

```
[trip_counts["AM"]+=1 if trip['start'].hour <12 else trip_counts['PM']+= 1 for trip in onebike_datetimes]
```

but I keep getting a syntaxerror

Comment: List comprehensions are used for creating new lists. Here you just trying to update the dictionary isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much clearer to keep your for-loop.

If you really want to make use of a list comprehension, you could do something like this:

```py
l = ["AM" if trip["start"].hour < 12 else "PM" for trip in onebike_datetimes]
am_count = l.count("AM")
trip_counts = {"AM": am_count, "PM": len(l) - am_count}
```

(And you don't need to initialize `trip_counts` if you use this)

Comment: This is inefficient. At most 2 of the calls to `count` are necessary; the rest are recomputing information previous calls computed.

Comment: @chepner Yes you are right! I've edited the answer to only call `count` once.

Comment: I've retracted my downvote, but this is still less efficient than it could be. You are still making multiple passes: one to compute the values you want to count, and `n-1` passes to do the actual counting of the `n` unique values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension (really, just a generator expression), but not in the way you are thinking. Build a generator of `AM`s and `PM`s, then use that to build a `Counter` instance.

```
from collections import Counter


trip_counts = Counter(("AM" if trip['start'].hour < 12 else "PM") 
                       for trip in onebike_datetimes)
```

---

A self-contained demonstration:

```
from collections import Counter
from types import SimpleNamespace


onebike_datetimes = [
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=9)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=3)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=14)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=19)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=7)},
    ]

trip_counts = Counter(("AM" if trip['start'].hour < 12 else "PM") 
                       for trip in onebike_datetimes)

assert trip_counts["AM"] == 3
assert trip_counts["PM"] == 2
```

Comment: I understand.  I am new to python and one thing I learned is that list comprehensions are faster to compute so I thought if I can do it.

Comment: They *might* be faster to compute, but they are *not* replacements for ordinary `for` loops.

Comment: I just ran some benchmarks, and if we're going by performance, then this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If this is a pandas `DataFrame` you're working with, why not filter values and sum them all at once?

Something like this might work:

```
trip_counts['AM'] = len(trip[trip.loc[:, 'hour'] < 12].index)
trip_counts['PM'] = len(trip[trip.loc[:, 'hour'] >= 12].index)
```

---

**EDIT**: I just ran some benchmarks on the answers given here, given that some people think that list comprehensions are automatically faster.

As you can see, the regular for-loop more or less has the best performance in this case, matched only by the use of `Counter` with a list comprehension as mentioned in one of the other answers here.

Note that I modified my Pandas implementation slightly to match how I believe your data might be structured, (i.e., not in a DataFrame), and thus there may a little more overhead to convert your data to a DataFrame on each run.

[image: benchmark]

The code to produce this plot is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from types import SimpleNamespace

import perfplot


def gen_data(n):
    onebike_datetimes = [
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=9)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=3)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=14)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=19)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=7)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=14)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=19)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=2)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=20)},
    {'start': SimpleNamespace(hour=12)},
    ]*n

    return onebike_datetimes


def use_vanilla_for(a):
#     onebike_datetimes = gen_data(n)
    onebike_datetimes = a

    trip_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

    for trip in onebike_datetimes:
        if trip['start'].hour < 12:
            trip_counts["AM"] += 1
        else:
            trip_counts["PM"] += 1
    return 1    
#     return trip_counts


def use_list_comp(a):
#     onebike_datetimes = gen_data(n)
    onebike_datetimes = a

    trip_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

    l = ["AM" if trip["start"].hour < 12 else "PM" for trip in onebike_datetimes]
    trip_counts = {i: l.count(i) for i in l}
    return 1
#     return trip_counts


def use_counter(a):
#     onebike_datetimes = gen_data(n)
    onebike_datetimes = a

    trip_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

    trip_counts = Counter(("AM" if trip['start'].hour < 12 else "PM") 
                       for trip in onebike_datetimes)
    return 1
#     return trip_counts


def use_pandas(a):
#     onebike_datetimes = gen_data(n)
    onebike_datetimes = a

    trip = pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda a: a['start'].hour, onebike_datetimes)), columns=['hrs'])

    trip_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

    trip_counts['AM'] = len(trip[trip['hrs'] < 12].index)
    trip_counts['PM'] = len(trip[trip['hrs'] >= 12].index)
    return 1
#     return trip_counts

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: gen_data(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda a: use_vanilla_for(a),
        lambda a: use_list_comp(a),
        lambda a: use_counter(a),
        lambda a: use_pandas(a),
    ],
    labels=["vanilla_for", "list_comp", "counter", "dataframe"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(10)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
```

Comment: you are right. I was curious if I can do it in a one line list comprehension. thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Assignments are statements.
Statements are not usable inside list comprehension. Use the loop

You should really **never** do it but for the sake of completeness:

```
trip_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

[trip_counts.__setitem__('AM', trip_counts['AM']+1) if trip['start']['hour'] <12 else trip_counts.__setitem__('PM', trip_counts['PM']+1) for trip in onebike_datetimes]

print(f"With list comprehension: {trip_counts}")
OUT: With list comprehension: {'AM': 1, 'PM': 2}
```